# Word for item or concept which has permanence?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm interested in a word (noun) to use to refer to an object or concept which has permanence.

For example, substituting ###, I would say

> "Many of the objects we interact with in real life are ###s, if you leave a ### for a while it will still exist when you come back.  But some things, like an ice cube, a bad smell, a virtual particle in physics or a local variable in programming, are not ###s."

The antonym, a word for an item which displays impermanence, would be interesting as well.

---

[EDIT]
The motivation is that I want to name an abstraction in my computer program. It is a type of container to put data in, instances of this container will hold data that (has) more permanence than a typical data (element) will. Typically, you name an abstraction after the thing it represents. If you have an abstraction that holds data about one person, you name the abstraction itself "Person". While trying to name this abstraction, I got curious to know if there was a generic word.

Comment: Any particular reason to name these as a class instead of just using an adjective? “Many of the objects we interact with in real life are permanent. If you leave them for a while, they will still exist when you come back. But some things, like an ice cube, are ephemeral.”

Comment: ***Constant*** *n, adj* : "Many of the objects we interact with in real life are *constant*, if you leave (such) a ***constant*** for a while it will still exist (to) come back (into view). But some things, like an ice cube, a bad smell, a virtual particle in physics or a local variable in programming, are not *constant*." (The first and last instants use *constant* adjectivally.) Ant.: *transient*

Comment: An adjective works better here. Also, a thesaurus would help. persistent, permanent, long-lasting, concrete (but then ice is concrete). Antonyms, short-lived, ephemeral, intangible.

Comment: @BraddSzonye The motivation is that I want to name an abstraction in my computer program.  It is a type of container to put data in, instances of this container will hold data that more permanence than a typical data will. Typically you name an abstraction after the thing it represents, if you have an abstraction that holds data about one person, you name the abstraction itself "Person".  While trying to name this abstraction, I got curious to know if there was such a word.

Comment: @derekv In that case how about naming it after a piece of furniture? (I like 'fixture' below). 'Cabinet' is already widely used, but how about chest/shelf/drawer/cupboard etc, all places where we store things of some permanence. Or relate it to food storage - jam jar, preserves, bottle, keg, cellar etc.

Comment: In software, the usual term is _persistent object,_ although that often implies serialization to disk. I don't know of a single-word noun equivalent.

Comment: Are you set on a noun rather than an adjective?

Comment: Part of the problem is so many terms are already taken to mean something else. @Mynamite - For my software I ended up using something along those lines, I'm calling it a "slot", this does have a meaning in programming but no meaning in my current environment.  Fixture would have been really good and in the future I think I'll consider using that, or like you said, cabinate, drawer etc.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Ideally it should be usable like a noun even if not typically a noun in proper speech.

Comment: @Bradd-Szonye I know, I would have used persistent object except for that implication.  Here the user shouldn't know or want to know how the object is "persisted".

Comment: @Kris Constant would be great but its already used to mean something different in my context, it means "can not be changed" and has nothing to do with its lifespan.  Though I could probably get away with intransient or some other invented derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One term which might suit your needs is ***fixture***:

> **3** : a familiar or invariably present element or feature in some particular setting; *especially* : a person long associated with a place or activity
>
> —source [Mirriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixture)

Though admittedly, it implies something that has merely been established for a long period of time, and is not necessarily *permanent*.

Comment: You bring up a good point, for my use, I just mean to talk about something which is relatively permanent compared to its contemporaries.

Answer (score 1):

Such an object (or concept) could be referred to as a ***static***.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would depend on the context of the permanence/impermanence.

A solid and dependable person could be a *rock* whereas a [fly-by-night](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fly-by-nights) is an unscrupulous or undependable person, literally one who disappears overnight.

An [ephemeral](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ephemeral) is a short-lived creature like a mayfly - it would be hard to find an antonym for this, given that all things die eventually, unlees you go for *mortals/immortals*.

With food you could refer to *staples*, *durables* or *imperishables* as opposed to *perishables*

Comment: +1 for ephemeral ... too bad there is not antonym, its tempting to make one up.

Comment: Some dictionaries list ephemeral as both adjective and noun, but I also found a different noun form [ephemeron](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ephemeron). The plural is ephermera and can also be used to mean "a matter of passing interest."  Great words!  Now, if only there where a direct antonym.

Comment: @derekv That's a good find. Not words used everyday by most people!

Answer (score 0):

I like ***"corporeal"*** for this concept of something *tangible* (another good word!), particularly since the antonym describes the fleetingness of ice cubes, etc.

> From the FreeDictionary.com:
>
> Possessing a physical nature; having an objective, tangible existence;
>
> being capable of perception by touch and sight.

---

> From Google Dictionary:
>
> cor·po·re·al
>
> /kôrˈpôrēəl/
>
> Adjective -
> Of or relating to a person's body, esp. as opposed to their spirit.
> Having a body.
> Synonyms
> physical - material - bodily - corporal - fleshly

---

> Antonyms from Thesaurus.com:
>
> cerebral, immaterial, intangible, mental, spiritual

Comment: Maybe the serial downvoter would care to leave a comment that might actually be productive and helpful?

Comment: I agree, would the downvoter(s) like to explain their reasons?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe it is because ice is corporeal but doesn't last.